# UIWebView input video from PhotoGallery iOS13

Tags: cordova, uiwebview, ios13, cordova-ios

When using the an input tag with type file, and selecting a video from the PhotoGallery in UIWebView running iOS13, the output is a file with size 0 and does not trigger an error in the ***onchange*** listener (i am not sure if this is supposed to actually trigger some error).

I am experiencing the same exact error described in [Uploading video file on website throw UIWebView in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37073565/uploading-video-file-on-website-throw-uiwebview-in-ios) despite the 3 year and context disparities.

This can be reproduced in a simple way:

- Simply create an application using UIWebView (i used cordova-ios@4.5.5 to do so) and then load an html that contains an input tag like:

```html
<input id="videoInput" type="file" />
```

This does not happens when using iOS prior to 13 or when using WKWebView or when using the Safari browser (understandably).

Another thing to note is, even without the *multiple* attribute, the UIWebView assumes the input is for multiple files.
Furthermore, loading a video file capturing a video at the moment works just fine. Capturing or selecting photos from the gallery also works like a charm. Only videos from the gallery fail.

I am aware that UIWebview is already deprecated and i am aware that Apple completely dropped UIWebView support (...), **but**:

Does anyone experienced the same and knows if this can be fixed **without upgrading to the WKWebView**?

Answer (score 1):

I have exactly the same problem as you. I have been looking for the answer for a long time. Finally found iOS13.0 above is the default will not open album read and write permissions, may be for security.